# Lost access to previous Documents in Lucid Charts after license revoked

Tags: lucidchart

I have lost access to Documents I had created in LucidCharts. I used LucidCharts for some time, then my license was revoked. Now that I got the license back, I am unable to see my previous Documents I had created.

My understanding is even if license revoked, I should have read-only access to my earlier documents. But this doesnt seem to be the case.